# How to pass value from serverless yml file to js file?

Tags: javascript, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

```
serverless.yml file    
provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs12.x
      memorySize: 512
      stage: ${opt:stage, 'test'}
      timeout: 30
    ##
    ##...
    custom:
      getValue: ${file(key.js):randomVal} //pass the string from here


key.js file
module.exports.randomVal = async (context) => {
    #code //get the string here
    console.log(context.providers);
};
```

In the above code, I am calling **randomVal()** function from the serverless yml file, I want to pass a string to that function from yml file.
Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the serverless docs, and there doesnt seem to be an official way to do this.

However, as a work around, you can just parse your serverless.yml file in your  key.js file using an npm package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml

Then do something like this:

```
custom:
  getValue:
    fn: ${file(key.js):randomVal}
    params: 
      someVar: foo
      someOtherVar: bar
```

When you parse serverless.yml in your key.js, you can then just use normal not notation to get the params:

```
const YAML = require('yaml')
const fs = require('fs')

const file = fs.readFileSync('./serverless.yml', 'utf8')
const parsedYaml = YAML.parse(file)

module.exports.randomVal = () => {
    let myVar = parsedYaml.custom.getValue.params.someVar
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use Serverless environment variables.

In your `serverless.yml` file you have a section `environment` under `provider`. Then those values will be populated for all your lambdas as process env varibles.

For example, having this section in you `serverless.yml`:

```
    
provider:
  name: aws
  environment:
    SOME_USEFUL_VALUE: 'some_val'
```

Then in your typescript files you can use this value as

```
const THE_USEFUL_VALUE = process.env.SOME_USEFUL_VALUE
```

Comment: The OP wants to resolve this at package time or deploy time. The env var is only accessible at runtime (which circumvents the question, but does not answer it exactly)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the variable to the `custom` section, and inside the imported function, you use the resolveVariable method.

```
serverless.yml file    
    provider:
      name: aws
    ## ...
    custom:
      theVar: "xx",
      getValue: ${file(key.js):randomVal}


key.js file
module.exports.randomVal = async ({resolveVariable}) => {
    #code //get the string here
    console.log(resolveVariable("self:custom.theVar"));
};
```

docs: [https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-properties-in-other-files:~:text=Exporting%20a-,function,-Note%3A%20the%20method](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-properties-in-other-files:%7E:text=Exporting%20a-,function,-Note%3A%20the%20method)